# Adding a query parameter to the Instagram auth redirect_uri doesn't work?

Tags: oauth, instagram, instagram-api

## Steps to reproduce

1. Register a redirect_uri in the client: http://example.com/publisher/auth
2. Direct a user to the /oauth/authorize endpoint with the redirect_uri including a query parameter:

   ```
   https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpublisher%2Fauth%3FinviteId%3D00001000-cf33-11e4-9f26-8789dd0b3e01&response_type=code&scope=basic&type=web_server
   ```

   For reference, those query parameters are:

   ```
   client_id=xxx
   redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpublisher%2Fauth%3FinviteId%3D00001000-cf33-11e4-9f26-8789dd0b3e01
   response_type=code
   scope=basic
   type=web_server
   ```
3. Authenticate an instagram user and allow the app.
4. The user is redirected back to the correct redirect_uri.
5. Use the code query parameter from the redirected URI to post to Instagram's /oauth/access_token endpoint.

## Expected behavior

The endpoint responds with 200 and an access token.

## ACTUAL behavior

The endpoint responds with:

```
code=400
error_type = 'OAuthException'
error_message = 'Redirect URI doesn't match original redirect URI'
```

## What I've Investigated So Far

To confirm that this is a problem with Instagram, I checked [the API docs](https://instagram.com/developer/authentication/) which very clearly state that adding query parameters to the redirect URI should be possible. I also tried varying only that query parameter. For example, when replaced with this /oauth/authorize URL I get the expected behavior:

```
https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?type=web_server&client_id=xxx&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpublisher%2Fauth&response_type=code&scope=basic
```

For reference, those query parameters are:

```
client_id=xxx
redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpublisher%2Fauth
response_type=code
scope=basic
type=web_server
```

## Notes

This question is actually a duplicate of [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27244367/instagram-api-add-query-param-to-redirect-uri) which actually didn't really turn out to be a question, and which never got any answers.

I have submitted a bug with Instagram, but I wanted to see if anyone had found this or come up with a workaround.

Comment: Are you providing exactly the same redirect URL when validating token? I'll soon need this functionality - will update

Comment: I did try adding query, It did work for me, maybe instagram support it now. Make sure encoding callback url.

Comment: @HosseinAmin Thanks for the tip. Didn't thought about encoding the callback url. You saved my day.

Answer (score 8):

Had the same issue today. To get the custom data passed between requests you must include it as `state` param. My authorize request url looked something like this:

> https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=SOME_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://example.com/auth/InstagramRedirect/**&state=855C0114-F860-420A-AEB1-A276644FCCEA**

Notice the **&** and **state**=...

Comment: And to send multiple querystring params across, send them URI encoded as the  "&state=" value. e.g. ```https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=SOME_CLIENT_ID&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http://example.com/auth/InstagramRedirect/&state=%26param1%3Dvalue1%26param1%3Dvalue2```

Answer (score 1):

You have to provide the redirect_uri with your extra search params as the **last parameter**:

> https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=be1b911b487f4919b9c2fb7df0c4142c&type=web_server&response_type=code&scope=basic&redirect_uri=https://wpwifidemo.alepo.net/instagram/joinus/?inviteId=00001000-cf33-11e4-9f26-8789dd0b3e01

User will be redirected to:

https://wpwifidemo.alepo.net/instagram/joinus/?inviteId=00001000-cf33-11e4-9f26-8789dd0b3e01&code=CODE

Comment: I know it has votes, but can somebody confirm that it still works?

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in 2021. @ssBarBee's answer above works

Answer (score 0):

It might be too late reply for this question. But i faced the same issue today & got this question already posted and solution for passing parameters to authentication URL is as follows.

It seems that your extra parameter is **type=web_server** , taking that into consideration, your URL for getting for code should be as follows

> https://www.instagram.com/oauth/authorize/?client_id=be1b911b487f4919b9c2fb7df0c4142c&redirect_uri=https://wpwifidemo.alepo.net/instagram/joinus/?**type=web_server**&response_type=code&scope=basic

And then while calling the accessToken API append your **redirect_uri** parameter with your passed parameter (not the same configured in the app).
e.g.

redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Fpublisher%2Fauth%3FinviteId%3D00001000-cf33-11e4-9f26-8789dd0b3e01?**type=web_server**

Comment: The extra parameter is actually `inviteId=00001000-cf33-11e4-9f26-8789dd0b3e01`, not `type=web_server`. And I don't think your solution will work, since it adds an extra query string to a URL that already has a query string. Essentially making it: `http://example.com/publisher/auth?inviteId=00001000-cf33-11e4-9f26-8789dd0b3e01?type=web_server`, which is a strange format for a URL.