# Instagram redirect url custom param error

Tags: php, instagram-api

My instagram config redirect url is:
https://facebook2.mygameinfo.com/instagramtest/callback.php?type=siteid

My php code is:

```
$instagram = new Instagram(array(
    'apiKey' => 'XXXX',
    'apiSecret' => 'ZZZZ',
    'apiCallback' => 'https://facebook2.mygameinfo.com/instagramtest/callback.php?type=siteid&state=' . $state,

));
```

I can not get state param when i logged to instagram,only have code parm return to me.But if logged status,login to instagram again，i can get state param and it's works.

So,why can not get my custom param（example：state）when i first login to instagram?

i don't know how to bind custom param to redirect url on instagram.please help.thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32590652/adding-a-query-parameter-to-the-instagram-auth-redirect-uri-doesnt-work

Comment: have you tried this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42507685/5436736

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding a query parameter to the Instagram auth redirect\_uri doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32590652/adding-a-query-parameter-to-the-instagram-auth-redirect-uri-doesnt-work)

Comment: thanks.Tahir Raza.i will check this